# How to produce a single row resultset without zero value fields when pivoting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I had a query that I needed to pivot, so I followed [this tutorial](http://www.boynux.com/creating-pivot-reports-in-mysql/) and I managed to pivot the data as I needed, except for one thing. I'm getting a result set like the following:

```
PRODUCT 1 | PRODUCT 2 | PRODUCT 3
0         | 0         | 9
0         | 39        | 0
61        | 0         | 0
```

I'd like to get these same numbers, which are correct, but this way:

```
PRODUCT 1 | PRODUCT 2 | PRODUCT 3
61        | 39        | 9
```

I want one row with those numbers with no zero values.

I have the following query:

```
select
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 1', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(vi_pdv_id_pdv))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 1', 
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 2', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(vi_pdv_id_pdv))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 2', 
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 3', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(vi_pdv_id_pdv))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 3'

from sf_visit_stock

join sf_visit on sk_vi_id_visit = id_visit
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_format on pdv_fo_id_format = id_format
join sf_group on fo_gr_id_group = id_group
join sf_channel on gr_ch_id_channel = id_channel

join sf_product on sk_pd_id_product = id_product
join sf_family on pd_fa_id_family = id_family
join sf_brand on fa_ba_id_brand = id_brand

and vi_pr_id_proyect = 5

group by ba_brand
order by ba_brand
```

I've tried `concat_group()` and I've been trying to solve this with `group by` but I'm not able to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ba_brand` is inside an aggregate function, you should be able to remove the `group by` clause and get the desired results.

```
select
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 1', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 1', vi_pdv_id_pdv, null)))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 1', 
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 2', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 2', vi_pdv_id_pdv, null)))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 2', 
ceil(
    sum(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 3', sk_warehouse + sk_exhibition, 0))
    / count(distinct(if(ba_brand = 'PRODUCT 3', vi_pdv_id_pdv, null)))
    ) as 'PRODUCT 3'

from sf_visit_stock

join sf_visit on sk_vi_id_visit = id_visit
join sf_pdv on vi_pdv_id_pdv = id_pdv
join sf_format on pdv_fo_id_format = id_format
join sf_group on fo_gr_id_group = id_group
join sf_channel on gr_ch_id_channel = id_channel

join sf_product on sk_pd_id_product = id_product
join sf_family on pd_fa_id_family = id_family
join sf_brand on fa_ba_id_brand = id_brand

and vi_pr_id_proyect = 5

group by ba_brand //remove this line
order by ba_brand //and this one
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that before, that way I get a one row resultset indeed but I don't get the same values of those numbers, they change for other ones u.u

Comment: @Metafaniel The numbers change because removing the `group by` alters the result of the `count` in the denominator.

Comment: @AirThomas, good catch,updated the answer to include the conditional in the count.

Comment: Note that `if` expressions are MySQL-only; a more portable solution would replace them with `case` expressions.

Comment: @Ken FINALLY! I tried all morning and I couldn't do iot Y-Y Thanks a lot for your help, now I have the desired resultset, THANKS!

Comment: @AirThomas I'll follow your advice and use `case` expressions instead! Thansk for helping me too =)